# Warum nennt man „Müllbeutel“ so?

Tags: meaning

Ich denke, dass eine Tüte aus Plastik oder Papier und ein Beutel aus Stoff besteht. Warum nennen man die „Müllbeutel“ so dann? Das ist auch Plastik, oder?

Comment: Man sagt aber auch Plastikbeutel. Ein Beutel kann aus Stoff bestehen, muß aber nicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich glaube, der Begriff *Müllbeutel* wurde von Marketing-Gesichtspunkten geprägt. Er ist nicht in allen Regionen Deutschlands gängig, in meinem Dialekt sagt man "Mülltüte" - ein "Beutel" ist allenfalls was, wo man sein Geld reintut - allerdings steht auf dem Produkt selbst auch bei mir zuhause "Müllbeutel" drauf.

Schaut man bei [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=m%C3%BCllt%C3%BCte%2C%20m%C3%BCllbeutel&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CM%C3%BCllt%C3%BCte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CM%C3%BCllbeutel%3B%2Cc0), findet man (*-Beutel* zugegebenermaßen häufiger) eine ähnliche Verbreitung von *Müllbeutel* und *Mülltüte*, schaut man sich aber Herstellerseiten an, findet man grundsätzlich nur den Begriff *Müllbeutel*.

Eine "Tüte" ist typischerweise ein Verpackungsmittel, das man beim Kauf von (losen) Dingen traditionell *umsonst* mitbekommt (siehe bis vor Kurzem Plastiktüten im Supermarkt, Pommestüten und die Bäckertüte für die Brötchen), impliziert also "kostet nix".

Wenn ich etwas verkaufen will, sollte ich bei der Wahl meiner Produktbezeichnung nicht einen Begriff wählen, der implizieren könnte, dass man mein Produkt "anderswo umsonst" oder "sowieso" bekommt - Deswegen steht auf der Wasserflasche "Mineralwasser" drauf und auf den Mülltüten eben "Müllbeutel"

Die anderen Antworten sind damit sicher nicht falsch, es gibt auch viele andere gute Gründe, warum man nicht "Tüte" draufschreibt, aber ich denke, das dürfte der Hauptgrund sein.

Comment: Ich würde eher annehmen, dass Beutel als neutraler, im gesamten Sprachraum benutzbarer Begriff gewählt wurde, auch wenn die Tüte verbreiteter ist als ich dachte: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f13b/ Ich Frage mich, we lange sie schon in Süddeutschland ist, aber zu ihr hatten wir hier ja schon Fragen.

Comment: @CarstenS Wie gesagt - Ich schließe andere (Mit-)Gründe nicht aus - Aber der Marketing-Grund ist zu bestechend und die Einheitlichkeit der vom Hersteller gewählten Bezeichnung im Vergleich zur Uneinheitlichkeit im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ebenfalls. Danke für den Verweis zum Atlas, hab' ich gar nicht dran gedacht.

Comment: In der Welt, in der ich lebe, sagt man im Alltag eher *Müllbeutel*. *Mülltüte* wäre auch möglich, ist aber seltener zu hören.

Answer (score 8):

Ein bloßer Blick ins Wörterbuch genügt.

Zum Beispiel steht im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Beutel) unter dem Stichwort *Beutel*, dass es sich um einen

> sackähnliche[n] Behälter aus weichem Material

handle. Ob das weiche Material nun Plastik, Papier, Zellstoff, Flachs, Kautschuk oder irgendetwas anderes ist, spielt für das Beutelsein keine Rolle. Genauso spielt es für das Beutelsein eines Müllbeutels keine Rolle, dass er aus Plastik besteht.

Comment: Steht bei "Tüte" was entscheidend anderes? Oder gilt "wenn eine Definition passt, dann **muss** es die sein"?

Comment: Ich verstehe den Einwand nicht. Erstens geht der Fragesteller davon aus, Tüten bestünden aus Plastik oder Papier - was richtig ist - und Beutel aus Stoff - was nicht allgemein richtig ist. Daher ist er verwirrt darüber, weshalb die meist aus Plastik bestehenden Müllbeutel eben _Müllbeutel_ genannt werden. Meine Antwort widerlegt lediglich seine Annahme. Zweitens gibt es neben der stofflichen Beschaffenheit tatsächlich noch ein entscheidenes Kennzeichen einer _Tüte_: die Trichter- oder Röhrenform, auch wenn sie etwa bei Einkaufstüten heutzutage kaum noch vorkommt.

Answer (score 7):

Das Wort *»Beutel«* bezeichnet nur die Form, nicht aber das Material, aus dem er besteht.

So bezeichnet man z.B. auch den Sack am Bauch von allen lebend gebärenden Säugetieren, die keine Plazenta haben, als *Beutel*. Die davon abgeleitete Bezeichnung für diese Tiergruppe ist dann auch: *[Beuteltiere](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beuteltiere).*

An vielen Gelenken im menschlichen Körper sitzen auch *[Schleimbeutel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleimbeutel)*. Das sind mit Flüssigkeit gefüllte Säckchen, die Druck und Reibung an den Gelenken reduzieren.

In vielen Dialekten Österreichs wird auch der Hodensack des Mannes als *Beutel* bezeichnet und als Schimpfwort benutzt. Z.B. im Wiener Dialekt: *»Beidl«*, das entspricht in der Schwere der Beschimpfung ungefähr dem *Arsch* (wienerisch: *»Oasch«*)

Im Mittelalter gab es den Beruf des *Beutlers*. Das war jemand, der aus Leder Wasser- und Weinbeutel herstellte. Solche Beutel werden auch heute noch z.B. in Spanien hergestellt und verwendet (»Bota« = spanischer *[Trinkbeutel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bota_(Trinkbeutel))*). Damit verwandt ist der aus Glas gefertigte (und somit starre) *[Bocksbeutel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bocksbeutel).*

Answer (score 7):

Eine **Tüte** ist ursprünglich ein kegelförmiges Behältnis. Denk an die *Eistüte*, an die *Schultüte*, an die *Pommestüte*.

Der Zweck ist natürlich, dass das ganze nach viel mehr aussieht, als es eigentlich ist. Und dass man das Ding mit einer Hand von unten anfassen und oben mit der anderen Hand Sachen rausgrabbeln kann.

(Außerdem gibt's auch noch die *Flüstertüte*. Da ist es einfach nur die Kegelform. Natürlich auch bei *der Tüte*, die man sich dreht.)

Müll in Kegeln darzubieten, dass man oben eine möglichst große stinkende Oberfläche und unten drin keinen Platz hat, hat glaube ich noch keiner versucht. Von daher ist die *Mülltüte* wohl eher ein sprachlicher Witz.

Comment: Der erste Absatz ist richtig.

Comment: Das mit der Kegelform ist interessant. Man lernt nie aus. :-)

Comment: Nach Deiner Antwort bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob Dir klar ist, dass "Mülltüte" absolut geläufig ist (vielleicht nicht überall).

Comment: Ja, es ist geläufig. Und ich denke immer an eine große Pommestüte mit Müll.

Comment: Ok. Jedem sein Idiolekt :)

Answer (score 5):

Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beutel) gibt es Beutel aus ganz unterschiedlichen Materialien. Das Wort ist daher schonmal korrekt.

Fraglich ist nun, warum sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch nicht die Mülltüte als alleinige Bezeichnung durchgesetzt hat, obwohl sie den Begriff enger eingrenzt. Das könnte daran liegen, dass das Wort Tüte nur für kleine Behälter verwendet wird. Das Wort Beutel hat eine größere Spannweite, so dass die Hersteller einfach auf alle Packungen dasselbe Wort schreiben können, egal, ob der Beutel nun 3 Liter oder 60 Liter fasst.

Comment: Die »Mülltüte« hätte es zumindest in Österreich aber ohnehin schwer gehabt, weil es bei uns keine Tüten, sondern Sackerl gibt. Und *Müllsackerl* (das sind kleine Müllsäcke) gibt's in Österreich tatsächlich, z.B. für Hundekot: https://www.easy-dogs.net/typo3temp/pics/9090f1caf4.jpg